# Stormcrawler: Apache Tika for parsing PDF properties

Tags: web-crawler, apache-tika, stormcrawler

I have added Tika as a reference to my StormCrawler implementation and that enables to fetch the PDF documents in the crawl. But, the *Title*, *Authors* and other properties don't get parsed. I have tried with different combinations to '*index.md.mapping*:' and added the corresponding properties to *ES_IndexInit*, but the content field in Kibana (index) for PDF's documents is always empty. Everything works for HTML pages. Can you please help with some pointers, if I am missing something or I can look at an example?

---

***es-crawler.flux:***

`name: "crawler"`

includes:
    - resource: true
      file: "/crawler-default.yaml"
      override: false

```
- resource: false
  file: "crawler-conf.yaml"
  override: true

- resource: false
  file: "es-conf.yaml"
  override: true
```

spouts:
  - id: "spout"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.AggregationSpout"
    parallelism: 10

bolts:
  - id: "partitioner"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.URLPartitionerBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "fetcher"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.FetcherBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "sitemap"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.SiteMapParserBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "parse"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.JSoupParserBolt"
    parallelism: 5
  - id: "index"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.bolt.IndexerBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "status"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.StatusUpdaterBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "status_metrics"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.metrics.StatusMetricsBolt"
    parallelism: 4
  - id: "redirection_bolt"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.tika.RedirectionBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "parser_bolt"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.tika.ParserBolt"
    parallelism: 1

streams:
  - from: "spout"
    to: "partitioner"
    grouping:
      type: SHUFFLE

- from: "spout"
  to: "status_metrics"
  grouping:
    type: SHUFFLE
- from: "partitioner"
  to: "fetcher"
  grouping:
    type: FIELDS
    args: ["key"]
- from: "fetcher"
  to: "sitemap"
  grouping:
    type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE
- from: "sitemap"
  to: "parse"
  grouping:
    type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE
- from: "parse"
  to: "index"
  grouping:
    type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE
- from: "fetcher"
  to: "status"
  grouping:
    type: FIELDS
    args: ["url"]
    streamId: "status"
- from: "sitemap"
  to: "status"
  grouping:
    type: FIELDS
    args: ["url"]
    streamId: "status"
- from: "parse"
  to: "status"
  grouping:
    type: FIELDS
    args: ["url"]
    streamId: "status"
- from: "index"
  to: "status"
  grouping:
    type: FIELDS
    args: ["url"]
    streamId: "status"
- from: "parse"
  to: "redirection_bolt"
  grouping:
    type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE
- from: "redirection_bolt"
  to: "parser_bolt"
  grouping:
    type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE
- from: "redirection_bolt"
  to: "index"
  grouping:
    type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE
- from: "parser_bolt"
  to: "index"
  grouping:
    type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

***es-injector.flux:***
 
`name: "injector"`

includes:
    - resource: true
      file: "/crawler-default.yaml"
      override: false

```
- resource: false
  file: "crawler-conf.yaml"
  override: true

- resource: false
  file: "es-conf.yaml"
  override: true

- resource: false
  file: "injection-conf.yaml"
  override: true
```

components:
  - id: "scheme"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.util.StringTabScheme"
    constructorArgs:
      - DISCOVERED

spouts:
  - id: "spout"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.spout.FileSpout"
    parallelism: 1
    constructorArgs:
      - "."
      - "seeds.txt"
      - ref: "scheme"

bolts:
  - id: "status"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.StatusUpdaterBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "parser_bolt"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.tika.ParserBolt"
    parallelism: 1

streams:
  - from: "spout"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["url"]

***pom.xml:***
 
`http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">`

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>xyz.com</groupId>
<artifactId>search</artifactId>
<version>search1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
                <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
                <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                              <mainClass>org.apache.storm.flux.Flux</mainClass>
                              <manifestEntries>
                                <Change></Change>
                                <Build-Date></Build-Date>
                              </manifestEntries>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <!-- The filters below are necessary if you want to include the Tika
                            module -->
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>flux-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-crawler-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-crawler-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-crawler-tika</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: can you share an URL for which you are missing the fields? Did you reload the index definitions in Kibana? (if you add a field it won't get refreshed automatically). Have you tried debugging e.g. with Eclipse when running the topology locally? How do you connect the Tika bolt to the rest of the topology? Do you get the text content for the PDFs?

Comment: Thanks Julien for the response. 
I am trying with a local url, but the pdf that I am working against is this:https://www.adobe.com/digitalimag/pdfs/about_metadata.pdf. 
I did refresh the definitions in Kibana.
I have not tried debugging [I will try that using the master branch]. 
PS:I have added my files to the original question.

Comment: I tried testing a PDF url with this "public class ParserBoltTest" test case, but this always fails with a null pointer exception. Do these test cases need any other prerequisites that need to be configured other than putting the correct url in the parse("...")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pom and flux files look ok. You could put the injection as part of the main flux to keep things simple.

What's in crawler-conf.yaml? Did you prefix the field names with 'parse.'?

Here is the metadata extracted from the URL you posted above

```
parse.dcterms:modified: 2004-09-29T20:21:18Z
parse.pdf:PDFVersion: 1.4
parse.access_permission:can_print: true
parse.pdf:docinfo:subject: By simple definition, metadata is data about data. Metadata is structured information that explains, describes, or locates the original primary data, or that otherwise makes using the original primary data more efficient. A wide variety of industries use metadata, but for the purposes of digital imaging, there are currently only a few technical structures or schema that are being employed. A schema is a set of properties and their defined meanings, such as the type of value (date, size, URL, or any useful designation). 
parse.pdf:docinfo:modified: 2004-09-29T20:21:18Z
parse.access_permission:extract_for_accessibility: true
parse.created: Fri Sep 24 15:56:30 BST 2004
parse.pdf:docinfo:created: 2004-09-24T14:56:30Z
parse.xmpTPg:NPages: 7
parse.access_permission:fill_in_form: true
parse.producer: Adobe PDF Library 6.0
parse.pdf:docinfo:title: About Metadata
parse.pdf:docinfo:producer: Adobe PDF Library 6.0
parse.dc:format: application/pdf; version=1.4
parse.access_permission:assemble_document: true
parse.access_permission:modify_annotations: true
parse.dc:title: About Metadata
parse.access_permission:can_print_degraded: true
parse.xmpMM:DocumentID: adobe:docid:indd:de7d50b0-0fc1-11d9-b0d4-cd42e793ca90
parse.xmpMM:DerivedFrom:DocumentID: adobe:docid:indd:a04d199f-0f11-11d9-b74d-bb0abf4f1ab0
parse.title: About Metadata
parse.Creation-Date: 2004-09-24T14:56:30Z
parse.modified: 2004-09-29T20:21:18Z
parse.resourceName: /digitalimag/pdfs/about_metadata.pdf
parse.dc:description: By simple definition, metadata is data about data. Metadata is structured information that explains, describes, or locates the original primary data, or that otherwise makes using the original primary data more efficient. A wide variety of industries use metadata, but for the purposes of digital imaging, there are currently only a few technical structures or schema that are being employed. A schema is a set of properties and their defined meanings, such as the type of value (date, size, URL, or any useful designation). 
parse.Last-Save-Date: 2004-09-29T20:21:18Z
parse.creator: Adobe Systems Incorporated
parse.pdf:encrypted: false
parse.trapped: False
parse.pdf:docinfo:creator: Adobe Systems Incorporated
parse.date: 2004-09-29T20:21:18Z
parse.meta:save-date: 2004-09-29T20:21:18Z
parse.Author: Adobe Systems Incorporated
parse.X-Parsed-By: org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser
parse.X-Parsed-By: org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser
parse.pdf:docinfo:creator_tool: Adobe InDesign CS (3.0.1)
parse.dcterms:created: 2004-09-24T14:56:30Z
parse.access_permission:can_modify: true
parse.subject: By simple definition, metadata is data about data. Metadata is structured information that explains, describes, or locates the original primary data, or that otherwise makes using the original primary data more efficient. A wide variety of industries use metadata, but for the purposes of digital imaging, there are currently only a few technical structures or schema that are being employed. A schema is a set of properties and their defined meanings, such as the type of value (date, size, URL, or any useful designation). 
parse.meta:author: Adobe Systems Incorporated
parse.access_permission:extract_content: true
parse.xmp:CreatorTool: Adobe InDesign CS (3.0.1)
parse.dc:creator: Adobe Systems Incorporated
parse.cp:subject: By simple definition, metadata is data about data. Metadata is structured information that explains, describes, or locates the original primary data, or that otherwise makes using the original primary data more efficient. A wide variety of industries use metadata, but for the purposes of digital imaging, there are currently only a few technical structures or schema that are being employed. A schema is a set of properties and their defined meanings, such as the type of value (date, size, URL, or any useful designation). 
parse.pdf:docinfo:trapped: False
parse.meta:creation-date: 2004-09-24T14:56:30Z
parse.xmpMM:DerivedFrom:InstanceID: de7d50af-0fc1-11d9-b0d4-cd42e793ca90
parse.Last-Modified: 2004-09-29T20:21:18Z
parse.Content-Type: application/pdf
parse.description: By simple definition, metadata is data about data. Metadata is structured information that explains, describes, or locates the original primary data, or that otherwise makes using the original primary data more efficient. A wide variety of industries use metadata, but for the purposes of digital imaging, there are currently only a few technical structures or schema that are being employed. A schema is a set of properties and their defined meanings, such as the type of value (date, size, URL, or any useful designation).
```

Your conf should contain something like

```
  indexer.md.mapping:
  - parse.title=title
  - parse.Author=author
```

As you can guess from the code of the test case, you need to add the file in *external/tika/src/test/resources/* and refer to the name of the file in the test code, as with *about_metadata.pdf* in the example below

```
 @Test
public void testMetadata() throws IOException {

    bolt.prepare(new HashMap(), TestUtil.getMockedTopologyContext(),
            new OutputCollector(output));

    parse("https://www.adobe.com/digitalimag/pdfs/about_metadata.pdf",
            "about_metadata.pdf");

    List<List<Object>> outTuples = output.getEmitted();

    // single document
    Assert.assertEquals(1, outTuples.size());
    // metadata
    Metadata md = (Metadata) outTuples.get(0).get(2);
    Assert.assertTrue(
            md.getFirstValue("parse.pdf:docinfo:subject").contains(
                    "By simple definition, metadata is data about data. Metadata is structured information that explains, describes, or locates the original primary data, or that otherwise makes using the original primary data more efficient."));

}
```

**UPDATE**

on closer inspection, the problem comes from your flux. The redirection bolt sends the tuple to Tika on a bespoke stream named 'tika'. The definition should therefore be

```
from: "redirection_bolt"
to: "parser_bolt"
grouping:
  type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE
  streamId: "tika"
```

Comment: Thanks Julien. I was able to solve this issue by just using Tika for html and pdf, and removing JSoup parser from the es-crawler.flux. I am still not sure what I might be doing wrong when using both JSoup and Tika.

Comment: @V_P you don't need to connect JSOUP to the indexer, the redirection bolt will do it
```
from: "parse"
to: "index"
grouping:
  type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE
```

Comment: I have not got a chance to check this out as I am stuck with another issue with SC. I am fine just using Tika for now but, I will give this a try and I am positive this update should fix it.

Comment: The SC has a setup for localhost ES, which works perfectly with --local and --remote. When I changed this to write to a Dev Elastic Search server (cluster) and I have updated, ES_IndexInit and es_conf.to have the properties for the url and cluster name, but this never write to that server. I am not sure what I am missing. I see no errors in the logs.

Comment: The SC when downloaded has a setup for localhost ES, which works perfectly with --local and --remote.                        When I change this to write to a Dev Elastic Search server (cluster) and I have updated, ES_IndexInit and es_conf.yaml (es.indexer.addresses and cluster.name) to have the correct values for the properties. ES_IndexInit creates the indexes on that server just fine as expected, but this never writes to that server. I see no errors in the logs and I see the URL shows as discovered in the logs. This does not even write to the Status Index. I am not sure what I am missing?

Comment: that's a separate issue - please open another question for it

Comment: Ok. I have opened that as a new question Thank you for your response.